# How to add value to progress bar based on API response in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a progress bar in my Angular app, what I want to do is, when the user clicks post comment is show the progress going from the value of 0 - 100 (when complete). So far I don't think what I have implemented does this, code so far is:

**ts.file**

```
 public commentProgress = {
    progress: 0
  };

onSubmit() {
    if (this.addCommentsForm.invalid) {
      this.addCommentsForm.setErrors({ ...this.addCommentsForm.errors, 'required': true });
      return;
    }
    let putData = Object.assign({}, this.addCommentsForm.value);
    console.log('form, ', putData)
    this.uploading = true;
    this.commentProgress.progress = 100;
    this.service.putServiceComments(putData, this.s_id).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log("comment sent");//On success response
      this.getServiceComments();
      this.uploading = false;
      this.commentProgress.progress = 0;
      this.addCommentsForm.get('comment').reset();
    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log(errorResponse); //On unsuccessful response
      this.error = true;
      this.uploading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

**html:**

```
 <progress *ngIf="uploading" class="progress comment-progress" [value]="commentProgress.progress" max="100"></progress>
```

What this code does is just show 100% of the progress not a gradual progress as the call is made on submit.

I even tried the following to no avail as someone had suggested.

```
    this.commentProgress.progress = 10 - 20 - 30 - 40 - 50 - 100;
```

Comment: You should report progress from your service putServiceComments method: `reportProgress: true,
    //   observe: 'events'` Check this example from Angular HTTP: https://stackblitz.com/angular/bbvdpovllej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuploader%2Fuploader.component.ts

Comment: Could elaborate a bit more, does it need that in the service file itself or in the above submit function

Comment: The progress should be reported from your service method and hence it should be in service file. check the `uploader.service.ts` from the example above and see how it is handled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont have information about progress from service, you can use  [indeterminate indicator](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview), or you can fake progress by having  endlessly growing value to 100. I implemented this function to achieve it:

```
public commentProgress = {
  progress: 0
};
private addition = 100;
private loading = true;

private addAddition() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.commentProgress.progress += this.addition / 2;
    this.addition /= 2;
    if (this.loading) {
      this.addAddition();
    } else {
      this.commentProgress.progress = 0;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Does this need to go in the Submit function? or ngOnit?

Comment: Code example is not based on Angular Material and you should have it in ngOnInit, but youu must set addition to 100 when you setting uploading to true. Default state of uploading is false.

Comment: just put addAddition in ngOnInit and add {{commentProgress.progress}} in html and see the magic